# Clone Magento project into a folder with a fresh Magento installation

Tags: linux, git, magento, github, git-clone

I have a GitHub repo with my Magento stuff. But i am using **.gitignore** for the fresh installation files and the repo contains only **my** files. 
On another computer I have a fresh install and now want to clone my custom files from the repo.

So, I tried:

```
git clone git://github.com/username/reponame.git /opt/lampp/htdocs/Magento
```

but I get a fatal error:

```
destination path '/opt/lampp/htdocs/Magento' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

If I clone without the second parameter (folder path) then I can clone the repo without errors but then it's in a new Magento duplicated folder Magento/**Magento**/app/... which is wrong.

OS: Ubuntu 12.04

IDE: NetBeans 7.2.1

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For those reasons I clone on a separate directory, and made a script to copy the static files (app, js, skin etc depends on what you want to change all) to the 'live' directory.

Comment: I did what I wanted with `git checkout`. But your idea is good, too. Could you provide your script, please? Even if it's too personalized I think everyone can edit it for himself.

Comment: Sure, I'm currently using a simple bash alias like `alias update-prod='git pull; cd <magento-directory>; cp -r <gitdir>/app .; cp -r <gitdir>/skin .; cp -r <gitdir>/js .; cp -r <gitdir>/lib .; cp -r <gitdir>/media .;`